# Full voice control for Mac

Tags: mac, voice-dictation

What's an app that let's my control my Mac with voice commands, always on, with no keyboard and no mouse? I'm talking about an iMac mounted on a wall that is always listening for voice control commands.

The only app support really needed is a web browser -- I'm not asking to control photoshop with my voice or something!

But it must be a setup that never requires me to connect a keyboard or mouse, even if it crashes and needs a reboot.

Comment: Mac never crashes :), but jokes aside, I would recomend to use a remote microphone (a Bluetooth) type, like you have it for the phone. This way you will have better control of the spoken word, and will prevent some "gigolo" from passing by saying stuff to your computer.

Comment: Good advice for those of us who live in areas with packs of roaming gigolos... :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to totally control your Mac with your voice, I should strongly recommend to use dragon dictate 3 for mac from Nuance. But you need to know some Applescript to implement some user command.
You should also buy Plantronics microphone for quality based recognition.
Regards
Claude